# How to render the my gitlab job pipeline artifact in the repository instead of downloading it

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, artifacts, gitlab-ce

I'm working on a project and I want the developers to view the job artifact report in the repository instead of downloading it

Comment: It would be beneficial to people who view your question to know in more detail what results have you got and why what you have tried is not satisfying your needs. Also, remember this is a community-driven site, so asking for a quick response is considered impolite.

Comment: you could commit the results to an dedicated branch like gitlab/hub pages do